# How can i get new form.vars.id in same page two different attachment form?

Tags: php, symfony-2.1

- When i first form file attachment get id from {{ from.vars.id }}

  dump(form.vars.id);

  Output :- My_first_project_new_image_attachment_file_id
  It is correct output this form
- When another form file attachment after first form attachment cancel.

  dump(form.vars.id);
  output :- old id is show My_first_project_new_image_attachment_file_id

  - but my expected result for another file is 
    Output :- My_first_project_new_response_attachment_file_id

### * How can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: First form has been load in browser how can i empty  first form load html ?

Answer (score 1):

When you first file attache then cancel or submit form after that empty load id .

Again you want to attache another form you get new this id because old id is empty now we get new id .